# UTF8 при чтении из файла на PERL

Tags: файлы, perl

Есть такой код

```
open FILE, '<:utf8', $filename;
my $str = "";
while(<FILE>) {
    $str = $str.$_;
}
print $str;
close(FILE);
```

Хочу считать файл. Если убрать параметр '<:utf8', то он считывается, но коряво. Хочу сделать с utf8. В чём ошибка?

Comment: что значит "коряво"?

Comment: С непонятными символами, вместо русских букв и некоторых других символов.

Comment: так вы читать файл хотите или вывести его на экран ? и чем вам помешал <:utf8 ?

Comment: Хочу считать файл в строковую переменную и вывести на экран.

Comment: что бы utf-8 хорошо выводило в консоль (в линуксе, на виндовс не пробовал) при выставленной utf-8 локали, нужно в начале файла об этом сказать перлу - добавить строку

    binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";

Comment: О, какая богатая тема :) @Святослав, для начала [тык мышой](http://habrahabr.ru/post/53578/)

Comment: Читал и не один раз. Дело в винде оказалось. Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А зачем читать построчно, если вы всё равно хотите слить прочитанное в одну переменную?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
$filename = 'utf8.txt';

use File::Slurp;
my $utf_text = read_file( $filename, binmode => ':utf8' );

print $utf_text;
```

Проверил (под Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) — работает.